# Test should pass on stream error, fail on success

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I'm trying to write a mocha test which passes on a stream error but fails if the stream ends without an error.

Detecting the error is no problem, but the finish handler is always called, even if the stream is forced to error out. In this code, the `error` handler's `should.exist(err)` assertion works correctly, but then the `finish` handler still throws an error.

```
describe('catch stream errors', function() {
  it('should throw an error', function(done) {
    var stream = failStream();

    stream.on('error', function(err) {
      should.exist(err);
      done();
    })

    stream.on('finish', function() {
      done(new Error('Why does this still run?'));
    });

    stream.write();
    stream.end();
  })
})
```

One workaround, which seems like a bit of a hack, is to scope an `errored` variable above the handlers, then flip it in the `error` handler and check the value in the `finish` handler. Seems like there should be a better way of handling this.

```
var errored = false;

stream.on('error', function(err) {
  should.exist(err);
  errored = true;
  done();
})

stream.on('finish', function() {
  if (!errored) {
    done(new Error('Error suppressed'));
  }
});
```

Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/joemaller/940bf9c5230cc772c720).

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Spies?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That should work, except that my actual use case is for a public package, so I'd prefer to avoid adding any new dependencies.

Comment: Perhaps there is an error in the implementation of this particular stream? Where does the stream come from?

Comment: I reduced this out of a gulp module, the `failStream` stream is a simple through2 stream that always throws an error. It's possible I messed up, the full source is in the gist linked at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*

I think we both agree what makes this problem challenging is that multiple Done() calls are being performed (two events firing). If Mocha sees multiple done calls, the test will auto fail.

It looks like if we can just prove that the error event occured, our test will be justified.

Sinon is a useful libray that provides "spies" that tell us when events are emitted.

Check this out:
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Spies

```
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');
var should = require('should');


// Writer
util.inherits(Writer, stream.Writable);

function Writer(opt) {
   stream.Writable.call(this, opt);
}

Writer.prototype._write = function(data, encoding, callback) {
  console.log(data.toString());
  // This will cause the stream to always return error
  callback(new Error('FAIL STREAM'));
};


var test =

module.exports.run =  function() {

  describe('catch stream errors', function() {
    it('should throw an error', function() {
      // setup the stream that always fails
      var stream = new Writer();

      // Initialize the spies
      var errorSpy = sinon.spy();
      var finishSpy = sinon.spy();

      // When the stream events fire, 
      // callback the respective spies
      stream.on('error', errorSpy);
      stream.on('finish', finishSpy);

      // Write to the stream, I setup the stream to 
      // always return an error when something is written.

      stream.write('hello');
      stream.end();

      console.log('errorSpy Called: '+ errorSpy.called);
      console.log('finishSpy Called: '+ finishSpy.called);

      errorSpy.called.should.equal(true);  // Mocha Test Fails If Error Event Was Not Emitted.
      finishSpy.called.should.equal(true); // Mocha Test Fails If Finish Never Happened.
    });
  });
};
```

Its not a pure native solution because it relies on Sinon. However, I think its still a good alternative.

Comment: The done handler is never called unless there's an error, so how would this fail on the inverse test case? If the stream *doesn't* throw an error, the test should explicitly fail.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I'll look through the code and see if I can revise the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution is to remove the finish listener from inside the error listener. This is similar to the [`cleanup`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f32a606e373ad57f684b0e511d6d6e4cbd48a812/lib/stream.js#L81-L96) method in node's `lib/stream` source file.

```
// Refactor out the listeners
var onerror = function(err) {
  should.exist(err);
  this.removeListener('finish', onfinish);
  done();
};

var onfinish = function() {
  done(new Error('Expected stream to throw an error.'));
};

stream.on('error', onerror);
stream.on('finish', onfinish);
```